# Input Text semelhante ao compartilhamento de arquivos do google drive

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input

[image: imagem do Google Drive]

Olá! Eu gostaria de saber como faço para que meu campo texto fique semelhante ao da imagem. Preciso pegar os valores do banco e deixá-los assim quando selecionados. Já funciona com o autocomplete do jquery, só preciso fazer isso para finalizar um formulário.

Comment: Luis poste o código que você já tem. Isso nos ajuda a te ajudar ; )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom, já resolvi essa pergunta. Um colega meu indicou usar o plugin select2 do jquery e aparentemente está funcionando.